# Потоки iostream и char*

Tags: c++, visual-c++, language-lawyer, стандарт, поток-ввода

Приведенный код компилирует [gcc](https://ideone.com/PMZZpC), но не компилирует Visual C++.

Кто из них неправ в строгом соответствии стандарту? Предполагаю, что это расширение gcc, но в стандарте доказательства не нашел (не нашел `>>(char*)` - это доказательство?).

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char* c = new char[200];
    char s[200];
    std::cin >> s;
    std::cin >> c;  // Visual C++ сообщает об ошибке C2679
    std::cout << s;
    std::cout << c;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Код перестал быть корректным начиная с C++20.

Если посмотреть [вот сюда](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2), видно что в C++20 убрали `>>` с параметром `char *`, и заменили его на `>>` с параметром `char (&)[N]`.

Первый имел тот же недостаток что и `gets`, поэтому неудивительно что его выпилили вслед за `gets`.